# How to get the average pitch of a .wav file without using Aubio?

Tags: python, audio, aubio

So, I am working on a program to compare the average pitch's of different .wav files. I had found a solution and it worked on repl.it using aubio, but for some reason every time I do
`pip install aubio` it gives about 50 red lines of error. Something about wheel build not working. So, is there any way to do this without aubio?

this is my error message:

```
C:\Users\GUNDERSON\Desktop\Tourretty>pip3.8 install aubio
Collecting aubio
  Using cached aubio-0.4.9.tar.gz (479 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\gunderson\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from aubio) (1.19.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: aubio
  Building wheel for aubio (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\gunderson\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\GUNDERSON\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-7tmi21r0\\aubio\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\GUNDERSON\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-7tmi21r0\\aubio\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\GUNDERSON\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-6_sc7w7f'
       cwd: C:\Users\GUNDERSON\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7tmi21r0\aubio\
  Complete output (32 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8\aubio
  copying python\lib\aubio\cmd.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\aubio
  copying python\lib\aubio\cut.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\aubio
  copying python\lib\aubio\midiconv.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\aubio
  copying python\lib\aubio\slicing.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\aubio
  copying python\lib\aubio\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\aubio
  running build_ext
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
  checking for aubio = 0.4.9
  Running "pkg-config --libs --cflags aubio = 0.4.9" failed: FileNotFoundError(2, 'The system cannot find the file specified', None, 2, None)
  Info: aubio 0.4.9 was not found by pkg-config
  Info: looking for *optional* additional packages
  checking for libavcodec
  Running "pkg-config --libs --cflags libavcodec" failed: FileNotFoundError(2, 'The system cannot find the file specified', None, 2, None)
  checking for libavformat
  Running "pkg-config --libs --cflags libavformat" failed: FileNotFoundError(2, 'The system cannot find the file specified', None, 2, None)
  checking for libavutil
  Running "pkg-config --libs --cflags libavutil" failed: FileNotFoundError(2, 'The system cannot find the file specified', None, 2, None)
  checking for libswresample
  Running "pkg-config --libs --cflags libswresample" failed: FileNotFoundError(2, 'The system cannot find the file specified', None, 2, None)
  checking for libavresample
  Running "pkg-config --libs --cflags libavresample" failed: FileNotFoundError(2, 'The system cannot find the file specified', None, 2, None)
  checking for sndfile
  Running "pkg-config --libs --cflags sndfile" failed: FileNotFoundError(2, 'The system cannot find the file specified', None, 2, None)
  checking for samplerate
  Running "pkg-config --libs --cflags samplerate" failed: FileNotFoundError(2, 'The system cannot find the file specified', None, 2, None)
  Info: libaubio was not installed or built locally with waf, adding src/
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for aubio
  Running setup.py clean for aubio
Failed to build aubio
Installing collected packages: aubio
    Running setup.py install for aubio ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\gunderson\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\GUNDERSON\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-7tmi21r0\\aubio\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\GUNDERSON\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-7tmi21r0\\aubio\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\GUNDERSON\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-nxsy7j61\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\gunderson\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\Include\aubio'
         cwd: C:\Users\GUNDERSON\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7tmi21r0\aubio\
    Complete output (24 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    running build_ext
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    checking for aubio = 0.4.9
    Running "pkg-config --libs --cflags aubio = 0.4.9" failed: FileNotFoundError(2, 'The system cannot find the file specified', None, 2, None)
    Info: aubio 0.4.9 was not found by pkg-config
    Info: looking for *optional* additional packages
    checking for libavcodec
    Running "pkg-config --libs --cflags libavcodec" failed: FileNotFoundError(2, 'The system cannot find the file specified', None, 2, None)
    checking for libavformat
    Running "pkg-config --libs --cflags libavformat" failed: FileNotFoundError(2, 'The system cannot find the file specified', None, 2, None)
    checking for libavutil
    Running "pkg-config --libs --cflags libavutil" failed: FileNotFoundError(2, 'The system cannot find the file specified', None, 2, None)
    checking for libswresample
    Running "pkg-config --libs --cflags libswresample" failed: FileNotFoundError(2, 'The system cannot find the file specified', None, 2, None)
    checking for libavresample
    Running "pkg-config --libs --cflags libavresample" failed: FileNotFoundError(2, 'The system cannot find the file specified', None, 2, None)
    checking for sndfile
    Running "pkg-config --libs --cflags sndfile" failed: FileNotFoundError(2, 'The system cannot find the file specified', None, 2, None)
    checking for samplerate
    Running "pkg-config --libs --cflags samplerate" failed: FileNotFoundError(2, 'The system cannot find the file specified', None, 2, None)
    Info: libaubio was not installed or built locally with waf, adding src/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\gunderson\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\GUNDERSON\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-7tmi21r0\\aubio\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\GUNDERSON\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-7tmi21r0\\aubio\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\GUNDERSON\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-nxsy7j61\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\gunderson\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\Include\aubio' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Some additional info:

- I am using the latest release of Python 3
- I am using windows
- I made sure to have the installer install the path variables
- PIP is installed
- When I checked the Wheel version with the update command, it said it was already at the latest version.

Comment: Hey, welcome! Could you share the error message? Maybe there's something there that could point to a solution and somebody would find it useful.

Comment: I made edits and added the error

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't just be trying to use the pip command, as it doesn't really build the file.

Step 1) Download the tar.gz of aubio. Latest version is 0.4.9, so be sure to download that.

Step 2) Extract the tar.gz

Step 3) Go to your command prompt/terminal and cd into the folder created by the extraction.

Step 4) do python ./waf configure command prompt. This gets your file ready for configuration. Be sure to already have a C++ compiler. I used Visual Studio's MSVC. Next, do python ./waf build inside command prompt.

Step 5) You should now be able to do pip install aubio without any problems, and it should properly install to your computer.